# Doctrine Distinct Count

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

What is the best practice for retrieving the `DISTINCT COUNT` on an entity collection?

In this example entity (`Customer`), I have a `oneToMany` relationship with `Orders`.

I want to count how many sales & products the customer has ordered:

```
> select * from orders;
+----------+----------+----------+
| customer | sale_ref | prod_ref |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 1        | sale_1   | prod_1   |
| 1        | sale_1   | prod_2   |
| 1        | sale_2   | prod_1   |
| 1        | sale_3   | prod_3   |
+----------+----------+----------+

> select count(prod_ref) from order where customer = 1;
+-----------------+
| count(prod_ref) |
+-----------------+
| 4               |
+-----------------+


> select count(distinct(sale_ref)) from order where customer = 1;
+-----------------+
| count(prod_ref) |
+-----------------+
| 3               |
+-----------------+
```

Here is the code

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Customer
{

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Orders", mappedBy="customer", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     */
    protected $orders;

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getOrders(): \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
    {
        return $this->orders;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getOrdersProductCount(): int
    {
        return $this->orders->count();
    }

}

class Orders
{

    /**
     * @var Customer $customer
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customer", inversedBy="orders")
     */
    protected $customer;

    /**
     * Non-unique sales reference
     * @var string $salesRef
     * @ORM\Column(name="sales_ref", type="string")
     */
    protected $salesRef;

    /**
     * Unique product reference
     * @var string $productRef
     * @ORM\Column(name="product_ref", type="string")
     */
    protected $productRef;

    /**
     * @return Customer
     */
    public function getCustomer(): Customer
    {
        return $this->customer;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getProductRef(): string
    {
        return $this->productRef;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSalesRef(): string
    {
        return $this->salesRef;
    }

}
```

Using the `Customer->getOrdersProductCount()` works perfectly fine for retrieving the product count and is said to be "good practice" as it doesn't hit the database with full loading of the collection:

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html

> If you mark an association as extra lazy the following methods on collections can be called without triggering a full load of the collection `Collection#count()`

However, in this example, a `Customer` can have multiple products for a sale - where the `salesRef` is non-unique. What is the best method for retrieving a `DISTINCT COUNT` of the `salesRef`?

This could/should be handled in the entity repository class:

```
class OrdersRepository
{

    public function getSalesCount($customer): int
    {
        return (int)$this->createQueryBuilder('o')
            ->select('COUNT(DISTINCT(o.salesRef))')
            ->where('o.customer = :customer')
            ->setParameter('customer', $customer)
            ->setMaxResults(1)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleScalarResult();
    }

    public function getProductCount($customer): int
    {
        return (int)$this->createQueryBuilder('o')
            ->select('COUNT(o.productRef)')
            ->where('o.customer = :customer')
            ->setParameter('customer', $customer)
            ->setMaxResults(1)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleScalarResult();
    }

}
```

This works BUT I need to load the entityManager/CustomerRepository in order to access these methods - whereas at least I can retrieve the product count from within the entity....

How could I access the distinct sales count from within the Customer entity - if at all?

I have considered using the [`Collection#filter()`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-collections/en/1.6/index.html#filter) method and/or looping through the `Orders` entity to create an array with the `salesRef` as the key and then using [`array_unique#count()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) but this doesn't seem "right" - I suspect I know the answer (*use the entity repository*) but I would prefer to be able to access the sales count from within the `Customer` entity - what is the best practice/method?

Comment: This can be done in many ways so there are that many answers. From simple but costly (`count($user->getOrders())`) to complex and efficient (writing raw sql) and everything in between. It all depends on what you are looking for.

Comment: For your case, I would say that using filter or array_unique is the better way. As this will not hit another database query. And you cannot use repository inside entity

Comment: Thanks - I am looking for an efficient method of retrieving the the DISTINCT count of sales from the Customer entity without loading the EntityManager/Repository... its a long-shot as I suspect that I will have to load the em/repository to efficiently/economically retrieve this but just wondering if its even possible from within the entity only

Comment: @JessGabriel yeah - this was where I was going but before go ahead wanted to canvas opinion on what is best way to solve this. Understood that EM/Repo not available/recommended within the actual Entity and it appears it would just do one single DB query to retrieve ALL records and then the Customer entity can filter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it and would be a more portable way of doing it. I did not test it though.

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('o');
    return (int)$qb
        ->select($qb->expr()->countDistinct('o.salesRef'))
        ->where('o.customer = :customer')
        ->setParameter('o.customer', $customer)
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Reference is here: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/query-builder.html#the-querybuilder

Hope this helps

Comment: I would also do it this way (or similar) but I don't think `->setMaxResults(1)` is needed with single scalar result.

Comment: Thanks - yeah, this works perfectly but what I am considering is whether I can economically retrieve the DISTINCT count of Orders sales_ref from within the Customer entity (without loading the EntityManager/Repository) - not sure if this is recommended/possible

Comment: In short - no. This is the best way. In more words - if you really don't want to use the repo within your controller function (I don't see a reason for that, this is how they are meant to be used) you can "break" the MVC structure and write your raw sql in its place.